# App Tracking Transparency on mac Silicon crash

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ipad, apptrackingtransparency

I have iOS application (that works properly on iOS) and it has enabled destination: **Mac(Designed for iPad)**. When run it on mac M1, the dialog doesnt appear and the code that it used to ask permissions for tracking always returns **ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus.notDetermined**
The code it here:

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { [weak self] status in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.didTrackingAuthorized?()
            }
            // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
            // and we are authorized
        case .denied:
            // Tracking authorization dialog was
            // shown and permission is denied
            print("FB - Denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            self?.setup()
            print("FB - Not Determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("FB - Restricted")
        @unknown default:
            print("FB - Unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

In documentation I read the Note about such behaviour:
[If you call ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus in macOS, ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus.notDetermined returns.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanager/authorizationstatus/notdetermined)

So the question is how in this case properly ask user permission for tracking activity on macos?

Comment: I don't believe that ad tracking is available on macOS. You will always get `.notDetermined` and if you call `requestTrackingAuthorization` then no dialog will be shown.  Your app should act as if `.denied` is the response

Comment: The advertising identifier is not available on macOS and will always return zeros

Comment: @Paulw11 so it is not required to be called on macos? I thought that application should ask in this case

Comment: It can ask (and should because that is the correct code to have for a .notDetermined case) but the dialog will not be shown and your completion handler will not be called. The rest of your code should treat `.denied` and `.notDetermined` the same